# Collapse not working (Bootstrap 4)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have problem with collapse in bootstrap 4.

I tried to control it via Javascript but it doesn't work:

Can anybody help me, please?

```
Codepen https://codepen.io/Ages/pen/dempQm
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

Comment: Please correct your codepen link to : https://codepen.io/Ages/pen/dempQm

Comment: ok next time I will specify the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine it just your ordering is not correct all is missing to include **jQuery** because bootstrap based in **jQuery**.

```
codepen : `http://codepen.io/AElkhodary/pen/odqYxP`
```

Answer (score 6):

Please find the below code for bootstrap 4 collapse

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is ok but I wanted to do it via JS action

Answer (score 0):

try this code for collapse :

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>

<div id="demo" class="collapse">
Lorem ipsum dolor text....
</div>
```

Here `data-toggle="collapse` is necessary to be placed in the need `anchor tag` or `button` which collapse the content. And the content which needed to be collapse should have class `collapse`.

Comment: Then this will help for script codepen : `http://codepen.io/AElkhodary/pen/odqYxP`